# Sitecore 8.1 Multivariate testing optimization shows no test status

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb

I have set up a Multivariate test in Sitecore 8.1. In Experience Editor i have a notification,it says item has a active test and Optimization tab shows red button but status shows no tests. I did check in the analytic database no test record found. I did deploy the Test from Workflow and its running. I am getting all options to stop, cancel and suspend. Sitecore is not testing my variations can any one help me to resolve this?

Comment: From Sitecore's Launch pad, chose the Experience Optimisation tool. In there what is currently displayed for your test?

Comment: Experience Optimisation Tool Shows nothing, Not even active test which is running. In Experience Editor under Optimisation view shows red symbol shows for running test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing it sounds like the `Sitecore_testing_index` is erroneous. Perhaps the index is invalid, not built or not present. This index is required for Sitecore's `Experience Optimisation` to find the `Tests` in their various states.

I recommend getting a default copy of `Sitecore.ContentTesting.Solr.IndexConfiguration.config` from a fresh install and copy it to the path `App_Config/Include/ContentTesting`.

Once that is done, rebuild the Index via the `Index Manager`. You should then be able to find tests in the `Experience Optimisation`.

If you're still having trouble I recommend replacing the entire contents of `App_Config/Include/ContentTesting` with the files from a fresh install. And re-indexing.

I also recommend having a look against the `Item` which has the `Multivariate test` it should be within the default field `Page Level Test Set`. It should have values something along the lines of this

[image: Page level test set]

If it is populated but you are still unable to the Test, follow this [guide how to create Multivariate Tests in Sitecore](http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/07/28/sitecore-8-content-testing-creating-multivariate-and-ab-tests/) to identify where something is going wrong.

Comment: I am having Sitecore.ContentTesting.Lucene.IndexConfiguration and Sitecore_testing_index working fine. I am able to generate fresh index file through Index Manager. As i am running Multivariate test both page level Test set and content test fields are empty.

Comment: Let me know why these field values are not populated? where i am going worng?

Comment: I am able to do Page tests successfully but Multivariate test on Component with different data source throwing below error Exception:         System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentItem
Source: Sitecore.ContentTesting
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.TestConfiguration..ctor(Item contentItem, ID deviceId, TestDefinitionItem test)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Data.SitecoreContentTestStore.LoadTest(TestDefinitionItem testDefinitionItem, ID deviceId)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetRenderingTest.